# Recreating inverse dataframe from existing data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe, that tells me how many signals were triggered (like a count value per hour), is there a way i can get with its inverse? like how many were not-triggered, that means, a zero in that hour when there was no signal?

Ex:

```
In [32]: datum.head()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[32]: 
     item_name  name   date_time           pred_value
476      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 06:00:00 2
477      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 07:00:00 2  
478      alpha  model2 2019-12-01 08:00:00 2  
479      beta   model3 2019-12-01 09:00:00 2  
480      beta   model1 2019-12-01 10:00:00 2
```

In the above example we can see that there is data count at `6th/7th` hours on `2019-12-01` but nothing later for `alpha` , similarly for `beta` we have at `9th/10th` hours.
I need to fill the dataframe with zeroes for rest of the hours.

I need to recreate a new dataframe something like below:

```
     item_name  name   date_time           pred_value
0      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 00:00:00 0
1      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 01:00:00 0  
2      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 02:00:00 0
3      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 03:00:00 0  
4      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 04:00:00 0
5      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 05:00:00 0  
6      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 06:00:00 2
7      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 07:00:00 2
...
23      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 23:00:00 0
24      alpha  model1 2019-12-02 00:00:00 0
.
.
478      alpha  model2 2019-12-01 00:00:00 0
478      alpha  model2 2019-12-01 01:00:00 0
478      alpha  model2 2019-12-01 02:00:00 0
478      alpha  model2 2019-12-01 03:00:00 0
```

Like this, we have have for multiple `item_name` (`alpha/beta/...`) and multiple `name` (`model1/model2...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add all missing combinations of values for `item_name` and `name` and datetimes:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

dates = pd.date_range(df['date_time'].min().floor('d'),
                      df['date_time'].max().floor('d') + pd.Timedelta(23, 'H'),
                      freq='H')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['item_name'].unique(),
                                  df['name'].unique(),
                                  dates], names=['item_name','name','date_time'])
df = df.set_index(['item_name','name','date_time']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
    item_name    name           date_time  pred_value
0       alpha  model1 2019-12-01 00:00:00           0
1       alpha  model1 2019-12-01 01:00:00           0
2       alpha  model1 2019-12-01 02:00:00           0
3       alpha  model1 2019-12-01 03:00:00           0
4       alpha  model1 2019-12-01 04:00:00           0
..        ...     ...                 ...         ...
139      beta  model3 2019-12-01 19:00:00           0
140      beta  model3 2019-12-01 20:00:00           0
141      beta  model3 2019-12-01 21:00:00           0
142      beta  model3 2019-12-01 22:00:00           0
143      beta  model3 2019-12-01 23:00:00           0
```

Another idea is if need add missing datetime per combinations `item_name` and `name`:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

dates = pd.date_range(df['date_time'].min().floor('d'),
                      df['date_time'].max().floor('d') + pd.Timedelta(23, 'H'),
                      freq='H', name='date_time')
df2 = (df.set_index('date_time')
        .groupby(['item_name','name'])['pred_value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(dates, fill_value=0))
        .reset_index())
print (df2)
   item_name    name           date_time  pred_value
0      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 00:00:00           0
1      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 01:00:00           0
2      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 02:00:00           0
3      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 03:00:00           0
4      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 04:00:00           0
..       ...     ...                 ...         ...
91      beta  model3 2019-12-01 19:00:00           0
92      beta  model3 2019-12-01 20:00:00           0
93      beta  model3 2019-12-01 21:00:00           0
94      beta  model3 2019-12-01 22:00:00           0
95      beta  model3 2019-12-01 23:00:00           0

[96 rows x 4 columns]
```

Also if there are different ranged of datetimes per combinations of first 2 columns use:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

def f(x):
    dates = pd.date_range(x.index.min().floor('d'),
                          x.index.max().floor('d') + pd.Timedelta(23, 'H'),
                          freq='H', name='date_time')
    return x.reindex(dates, fill_value=0)
df3 = (df.set_index('date_time')
        .groupby(['item_name','name'])['pred_value']
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index())
print (df3)
 item_name    name           date_time  pred_value
0      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 00:00:00           0
1      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 01:00:00           0
2      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 02:00:00           0
3      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 03:00:00           0
4      alpha  model1 2019-12-01 04:00:00           0
..       ...     ...                 ...         ...
91      beta  model3 2019-12-01 19:00:00           0
92      beta  model3 2019-12-01 20:00:00           0
93      beta  model3 2019-12-01 21:00:00           0
94      beta  model3 2019-12-01 22:00:00           0
95      beta  model3 2019-12-01 23:00:00           0

[96 rows x 4 columns]
```